# UV mapping width and height

Tags: xna, c#, .net

I am looking at the following C# code on howto construct a cube. It draws a cube using one texture on everyface.

```
 private void ConstructCube()
    {
        _vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[NUM_VERTICES];

        // Calculate the position of the vertices on the top face.
        Vector3 topLeftFront = Position + new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 topLeftBack = Position + new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 topRightFront = Position + new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 topRightBack = Position + new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) * Size;

        // Calculate the position of the vertices on the bottom face.
        Vector3 btmLeftFront = Position + new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 btmLeftBack = Position + new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 btmRightFront = Position + new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 btmRightBack = Position + new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f) * Size;

        // Normal vectors for each face (needed for lighting / display)
        Vector3 normalFront = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 normalBack = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 normalTop = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 normalBottom = new Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 normalLeft = new Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) * Size;
        Vector3 normalRight = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) * Size;

        // UV texture coordinates
        Vector2 textureTopLeft = new Vector2(1.0f * Size.X, 0.0f * Size.Y);
        Vector2 textureTopRight = new Vector2(0.0f * Size.X, 0.0f * Size.Y);
        Vector2 textureBottomLeft = new Vector2(1.0f * Size.X, 1.0f * Size.Y);
        Vector2 textureBottomRight = new Vector2(0.0f * Size.X, 1.0f * Size.Y);

        // Add the vertices for the FRONT face.
        _vertices[0] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topLeftFront, normalFront, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[1] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftFront, normalFront, textureBottomLeft);
        _vertices[2] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightFront, normalFront, textureTopRight);
        _vertices[3] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftFront, normalFront, textureBottomLeft);
        _vertices[4] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmRightFront, normalFront, textureBottomRight);
        _vertices[5] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightFront, normalFront, textureTopRight);

        // Add the vertices for the BACK face.
        _vertices[6] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topLeftBack, normalBack, textureTopRight);
        _vertices[7] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightBack, normalBack, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[8] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftBack, normalBack, textureBottomRight);
        _vertices[9] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftBack, normalBack, textureBottomRight);
        _vertices[10] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightBack, normalBack, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[11] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmRightBack, normalBack, textureBottomLeft);

        // Add the vertices for the TOP face.
        _vertices[12] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topLeftFront, normalTop, textureBottomLeft);
        _vertices[13] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightBack, normalTop, textureTopRight);
        _vertices[14] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topLeftBack, normalTop, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[15] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topLeftFront, normalTop, textureBottomLeft);
        _vertices[16] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightFront, normalTop, textureBottomRight);
        _vertices[17] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightBack, normalTop, textureTopRight);

        // Add the vertices for the BOTTOM face. 
        _vertices[18] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftFront, normalBottom, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[19] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftBack, normalBottom, textureBottomLeft);
        _vertices[20] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmRightBack, normalBottom, textureBottomRight);
        _vertices[21] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftFront, normalBottom, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[22] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmRightBack, normalBottom, textureBottomRight);
        _vertices[23] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmRightFront, normalBottom, textureTopRight);

        // Add the vertices for the LEFT face.
        _vertices[24] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topLeftFront, normalLeft, textureTopRight);
        _vertices[25] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftBack, normalLeft, textureBottomLeft);
        _vertices[26] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftFront, normalLeft, textureBottomRight);
        _vertices[27] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topLeftBack, normalLeft, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[28] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmLeftBack, normalLeft, textureBottomLeft);
        _vertices[29] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topLeftFront, normalLeft, textureTopRight);

        // Add the vertices for the RIGHT face. 
        _vertices[30] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightFront, normalRight, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[31] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmRightFront, normalRight, textureBottomLeft);
        _vertices[32] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmRightBack, normalRight, textureBottomRight);
        _vertices[33] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightBack, normalRight, textureTopRight);
        _vertices[34] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(topRightFront, normalRight, textureTopLeft);
        _vertices[35] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(btmRightBack, normalRight, textureBottomRight);

        _isConstructed = true;
    }
```

Now, all of the UV coordinates are represented as a fraction out of 1, 1 being the total size of the texture. So, how on earth could I map only one size of a texture to my cube??? For example, have a texture with 6 squares and have each square be one case. I know how to map the coordinates, but even if I map the right coordinates, it will still draw everything that is to the right of the Y coordinates, and under the X coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

UV coordinates act as a normalized representation of a texel to sample at the particular x/y location within that texture. Whenever a vertex is passed through the shading pipeline, a portion of the pipeline will appropriately interpolate the UV coordinates for each pixel. Here is a good description of UV mapping in the context of directx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Accurate answer but if op understood the definition to the words you are using he probably wouldn't have to ask the question. You answer would be much more noob friendly if you would break the concepts down and define your terms a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

So, it depends on how the pixel shader is written, but assuming it's completely generic (pass through the UV coordinates to the texture sampler), then the UV coordinates specify a location on the texture you're sampling.  (0,0) is the upper left corner, and (1,1) is the bottom right corner.  Ordinarily, anyway.  I'm a little unclear why (0,0) is the upper right texture coordinate, and further why the elements of the UV vector are being multiplied by Size.x and Size.y, but the concept I want to explain is more general than that, so I suppose it doesn't matter in this case.

It sounds like you want to use your texture as a Texture Dictionary, where subtextures are sampled from the Texture Dictionary, rather than taking the whole texture and using that.  This has a number of advantages, like  being able to batch together multiple render calls and reducing congestion, but that's not what you asked.

First, you need a method of identifying where, within the texture, each subtexture lies.  If you had a 64x64px texture, and it held 4 32x32px subtextures, then you'd have:

```
texture 1 at (0,0) with size (32,32)
texture 2 at (0,31) with size (32,32)
texture 3 at (31,0) with size (32,32)
texture 4 at (31,31) with size (32,32)
```

in terms of UV coordinates, that corresponds to

```
texture 1 UL (0,0)                 BR (32.0/64.0,32.0/64.0)
texture 2 UL (0,32.0/64.0)         BR (32.0/64.0,1.0)
texture 3 UL (32.0/64.0,0)         BR (1.0,32.0/64.0)
texture 4 UL (32.0/64.0,32.0/64.0) BR (1.0,1.0)
```

From those UpperLeft and BottomRight positions you can generate the four corners of each texture necessary to specify the face of each cube.  Then, you simply pass it to the appropriate cube face.

So, that's the standard mapping which you said you understood.  Now, onto some suspicions why, if you did that, it didn't work:

Notice that the code you provided is multiplying your UV coordinates by Size.  It could be your shaders are doing something funky, like dividing by Size again, putting it back in the 0->1 range before texture sampling.  If that is what's happening, and you do a mapping that doesn't multiply by Size, then your biggest value will be 1/Size, which might all end up inside the same subtexture, or at the very least offset.  So, check out the PS if you can, and if you can't then just play around with that.  If you have more specific questions, or if this didn't actually address your actual question, let me know and I can take another crack at it.